# react-chartjs-2 Charts ignoring size defined

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap, react-chartjs-2

I'm using react-chartjs-2 to create charts, but recently for an unknown reason they aren't adhering to the dimensions that I've assigned to them.

```
<Card style={{height: 900,}}>
      <CardBody>
        <CardHeader>Jobs Done Per Day</CardHeader>
        <br />
        <Line
          data={data}
          height={300}
          width={300}
          responsive={true}
          options={{
            barValueSpacing: 20,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
          }}
        />
      </CardBody>
    </Card>
```

Above is the code for one of the charts I am making, the issue is that even though the height of the card is 900 and the height of the chart is assigned to 300, the chart is larger than the card holding it.

Additionally if I remove the height styling from the card tag then the chart just keeps getting taller.